# How can I fix my Sony Vaio, Model: PCG61a12 grapics problem in Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, graphics, intel-graphics, sony

The conversion of my laptop from Wins 7 to Ubuntu has generally been good. Except one thing.

My graphics in games.

For a computer that has a Blue-Ray player in it, a game like "Torchlight 2" is choppy and even in a small windows still stutters on any settings and Guild War 1 is practically unplayable (the thing at one point ran Rift well, so I know somethings wrong).

The problem is I don't if  it's my distribution (I duo-boot the laptop version and GamePak Distribution) or my non-ability to install any graphics through the use the Linux Intel update or through any of the auto installers.

Comment: Can you please give more info, like what graphics card you're using?

Comment: From Steam. Video Card Driver:  Intel Open Source Technology Center Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2. Driver Version:  3.0 Mesa 10.2.2. OpenGL Version: 3.0. Desktop Color Depth: 24 bits per pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Linux generally has worse to far worse support for OpenGL games, at least under Intel HD Graphics.

What you're experiencing is the poor quality of Intel drivers under Linux.

Sorry to say this, but stick to Windows for gaming until Vulkan comes out on Linux.